# Read a csv file which contains an arrow symbol

Tags: r

```
df <- read.table("sample.csv", fill = TRUE, sep=";", quote ="",header=F)
```

This is the command I am using to read a csv file which has semicolon as a separator and `->` (arrow) symbols in between.

**Below is the error I am getting**:

```
Warning message:
In read.table("sample.csv", fill = TRUE, sep = ";",  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'sample.csv'
```

I have searched extensively in stack overflow but didn't get perfect answer. one said to remove those arrow symbols and read, it worked but would like to know if there is any direct way reading such files without manual intervention.

Sample data:

"5;"""";"""";"""";""12 months"";""y"";""2015-08-30"";""valid"";""2016-08-30"";""2016-09-01"";""51"";""BBC"";""4"";""Official"";""2015-08-30"";""BBC1"";""ISEC v6.0  Windows 2008 v6.0"";""C"";""4"";"""";"""";""0"";""0"";"""";""ABC"""

"5;"""";"""";"""";""12 months"";""y"";""2015-08-30"";""valid"";""2016-08-30"";""2016-09-01"";""51"";""BBC"";""5"";""Official"";""2015-08-30"";""BBC1"";""ISEC v6.0  Windows 2008 v6.0"";""C"";""5"";"""";"""";""0"";""0"";"""";""ABC"""

Symbols are not showing in above sample. Look at below picture.

[you can see special characters in below picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1R3C.jpg)

Comment: Could you post your last and second to last rows? Or at least one row? :) I suspect the last row is different from the others.. Anyway I'll be glad to help if you post a sample of your data. (post it editing your answer)

Comment: This error message sometimes happens when there is no newline at the end of the file. It might not be about the arrow. Try adding an empty newline at the end (it works on my computer with a simulated csv file)

Comment: @scoa I don't think that is the reason, when I remove arrow symbol manually and read it worked fine.